# Using random numbers in switch/case statement in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, case-statement

wanted to use a switch statement in Java, but the variable in the switch-statement (switch(variable)) should be compared to random numbers in the case-statements (case(randomNumber)). But I get an error message like that: "case expressions must be constant expressions". **So does my case-statements doesn't work with random numbers?** I thought that the error message means that i have to preface the variables with "final", but that didn't work either. **So, are if ... else statements the only way?** I hope I explained my problem well enough to understand.
(I'm just beginning with java and the whole terminology that comes with coding)

```
       int number = 6; //some number between 0-9
   int randomNumber1 = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));
   int randomNumber2 = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));
   int randomNumber3 = ((int)(Math.random() * 10));
   
   switch(number)
   {
   case(randomNumber1):
       //some code here
   case(randomNumber2):
       //some code here    
   case(randomNumber3):
       //some code here
   default:
       //some code here
   }
```

Comment: I tested this by creating new variables and doing case(variable), but that didn't even work which is surprsing.

Comment: Considering the targets of a switch statement must be constants, it's not surprising at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is not working is because you are doing

> case(variable)

When I changed this to an actual number, it started working for me. It is saying constant expression required because it wants an actual number, not a number stored in a variable.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As explained, the `(expression)` in a `case (expression):` statement must be a constant.

As for if-else being the only way, another possibility (depending on what you're trying to do overall) is to use the random numbers as keys in a map, with values of objects with a method that can be executed to perform the action you want.

```
    Interface MyAction
    {
        public void doMyAction() {};
    }

    public class Eight implements MyAction
    {
        public void doMyAction() { System.out.println("I'm an eight"); }
    }

    public class Four implements MyAction
    {
        public void doMyAction() { System.out.println("I'm a four"); }
    }

    // ...
    HashMap<Integer, MyAction> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
    actionMap.put(8, new Eight());
    actionMap.put(4, new Four()); 

    // ...
    MyAction myAction = actionMap.get(randomNumber);
    if (myAction == null) { System.out.println("Don't have one of those"); }
        else { myAction.doMyAction(); }
```

It's hard to see what overall goal you're trying to accomplish, which may be why you're not getting more response -- people here often don't like proposing something that may turn out to be 'wrong', even for a situation that wasn't explained completely.

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the error you are getting, `switch` can only be used with [constant expressions](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oreily/java/langref/ch04_16.htm). To achieve what you want, you can only use branching with `if`, `else if`, and `else`.

```
if(number == randomNumber1){
    //some code here
} else if(number == randomNumber2){
    //some code here
} else if(number == randomNumber3){
    //some code here
} else {
    //some code here
}
```